# Mod_Rewrite Rewrite URL without change address bar

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, web

OK, I saw many different posts about this subject.
But I just don't get it how this all works. 
So I have to post this question again.

So I know I can do a Rewrite OR Redirect with the Mod_Rewrite.
I Also know, that If I don't want that the address bar changes I have to not set the R Prop behind my Rule.

I thought about all these things and created my rule:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blabla\.ch$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.blabla\.ch$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/blabla\.ch\/wordpress" [L]
```

So you can see, If someone enters the domain www.blabla.ch I want to rewriter it to www.blabla.ch/wordpress, without the addressbar is changed.

But that just won't work.

I wrote this Rule into the .htaccess of the root www Folder.

I tried different things, mentioned on different websites.
Could please someone tell me, why this isn't working ? what is my mistake ? Where am I just thinkin the wrong way?

Comment: You have restarted the server after the configuration change right ?

Comment: couldn't have no direct acces to the server, just over FTP. Is a webspace hoster.

Comment: Sorry I dont know how it works on webspace, your configuration looks ok. But i think that the configuration has not been loaded

Comment: Also when I wrote it into the .htaccess file of the www Folder ?